# set exact width to td- text overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the overflow text but I don't succeed. Maybe someone can help me.
I want the td's width to be exactly 10 px and any overflow text should be hide.
Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9CyU/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
td {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the table-layout style to fixed. See a revised [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9CyU/1/). Also check out http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout